# Doubt about the coordinates of a moving Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

My friend asked me about the geometry of a moving black hole with constant velocity. My first attempt to cast its metric tensor was:

> $1.$ Start with Schwarzschild metric in spherical coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$.
>
> $2.$ Perform a coordinate transformation for cartesian coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi) \to (t,x,y,z)$.
>
> $3.$ Finally, perform a boost in just the $x$-direction $(t,x,y,z) \to (\gamma(t'-vx'),\gamma(x' -vt'),y',z')$.

I didn't finish the calculations but my question is that if I follow the steps of my reasoning above, will I reach a metric tensor $g$ that describes a black hole moving with a constant velocity?

Comment: The post contains [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/238519) that does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/444439/180269) might be useful.